# SVM classifier and test images

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, svm, encode

I have 5 classes in the training set where each class has 100 training images. I have created 5 classes in the test folder. Now each test image will be compared against the training classes and based on it's closeness to one of the training classes it will be labelled for the corresponding test class. I want to know if I am doing the right steps in SVM classifier ?

Comment: Be more precise. I don't understand the question. Maybe you are asking how to do multiclass-learning with SVMs, but maybe not. If so, check out the terms OneVsRest and OneVsOne in multiclass-learning.

Comment: start with opencv's SVM examples, replace their data with yours. See what results your are getting and continue from there (http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/ml/non_linear_svms/non_linear_svms.html)

Answer (score 1):

So basically you have the following structure:

train

```
|-- class1
|   |-- 1.pgm
|   |-- ...
|   |-- 100.pgm
|-- class2
|   |-- 1.pgm
|   |-- ...
|   |-- 100.pgm
...
|-- class5
|   |-- 1.pgm
|   |-- ...
|   |-- 100.pgm
```

test

```
|-- class1
|   |-- 1.pgm
|   |-- ...
|   |-- n.pgm

|-- class5
|   |-- 1.pgm
|   |-- ...
|   |-- n.pgm
```

The next step is to extract a descriptor from the train images. Using the extracted features, you generate (train) a classification model. In the end, you use the same encoding method to extract the features from the test images and then use the trained model to make predictions.

Comment: thank you Liviu Stefan. So do I need to first categorize all the test data manually into different classes like in the training data-set? And should each test class have the same number of images and that number can be different from the number of images in the training class ? Then what is the role of SVM classifier ?

Comment: No, you do not have to categorize all the test data manually intro different classes. Also the test classes can have any number of images. You use the SVM to train a classification model base on the train images which you'll use to make prediction for the test images.

Comment: I am summarising what I do. Please comment. I have 5 classes with labels "chat", "bike", "night", "eat", "office". Each class has 100 images. I have one folder "test_data" with 100 random images.  I have a vocab.mat, train_features(train_bag_of_sift.mat) and test_features(test_bag_of_sift.mat). The training data is trained by svmtrain function. " scores = [scores ; (W' * test_image_feats' + B) ]" gives the scores and the corresponding index category(index(max_score)) is the predicted category. In order to find the accuracy this will be compared against the ground truth values.